# Can't run tests from Test Explorer in VS 2012

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2012

I've recently installed the release version of Visual Studio 2012, and am having lots of problems with the Test Explorer.  For example, when I right click a test in the Test Explorer to select it, and select "Debug Selected Tests", it runs the test for me, but not in debug mode - it never hits any breakpoints I've set in the test.  Also, if I right click a test in the Test Explorer to select it, and then "Open Test" from the context menu that comes up, nothing happens, the test does not open.

I wanted to check and see if anyone else is seeing similar problems with the VS 2012 Test Explorer, and what can be done to fix the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug in Visual Studio 2012.  The workaround I'm currently using is to run the tests from Resharper's Test Interface. Hopefully there will be a fix for the problem soon.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution build configuration, is the test project set to build?

Comment: Yes, the test project is set to build in the Configuration Manager.